# Get the value of a selected option

Tags: jquery, forms, yui

I searched my *ss off, but couldn't find the answer online or write the correct code myself. I did manage to get this to work in jQuery, but I need to get it rolling with YUI 2.7.

What am I trying to do?
Get the selected value of a drop down menu and write it in another form field.

This works with jQuery:

```
function displayVals() {
 var subjectValue = $("select").val();
 var subjectName = $("select option[value='"+subjectValue+"']").text()
// set the value of another form field  
$("#TextInput_subject").val("Technische ondersteuning > " + subjectName);
}

$("#SelectionInput_reason").change(displayVals);
displayVals();


// the select menu we are trying to get the selection from..
<select id="SelectionInput_reason">
<option value="">--</option>
<option value="27" name="Televisie" >Televisie</option>
<option value="28" name="Internet" >Internet</option>
<option value="29" name="Mobiel Internet" >Mobiel Internet</option>
<option value="30" name="Telefonie" >Telefonie</option>
<option value="47" name="Horizon" >Horizon</option>
<option value="48" name="Online TV" >Online TV</option>
</select>
```

This is what I got with YUI where I only get the ID back of the selected option:

```
getValue = function(e) {
var selectedValue = this.value;
alert(selectedValue); 
} 

YAHOO.util.Event.addListener("SelectionInput_reason", "change", getValue);
```

I really can't get any further and it's really frustrating! Hope someone can point me into the right direction.

Comment: Here's the winning code. Had to play around with .name and .label as IE and Safari/Firefox/Chrome get undefined for one or the other. But an IF statement fixed that.


    getValue = function(e) {
    var selectedText = this.options[this.selectedIndex].name;
    
    if (selectedText == undefined) {
        selectedText = this.options[this.selectedIndex].label;
    } 

    document.getElementById('TextInput_subject').value = selectedText;
    } 
    YAHOO.util.Event.addListener("SelectionInput_reason", "change", getValue);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look into `.options` and `.selectedIndex` attributes of the `<select>` element.

```
getValue = function() {
    var selectedValue = this.value;
    var selectedText = this.options[this.selectedIndex].getAttribute('value');
    alert(selectedValue); 
    alert(selectedText); 
}
```

Test: http://jsfiddle.net/smHRg/

Comment: var selectedText = this.options[this.selectedIndex].label; doesn't work... BUT! .name did the trick. Now I only need to find out how to push it into another text input field.

Comment: Hmm.. it turns out it now works in IE, but on Mac (Safari, FireFox, Chrome) this returns UNDEFINED. Which pretty much spoiled the rush I was just in... so still searching for a solution I'm afraid.

Comment: I think `this.options[this.selectedIndex].getAttribute('value')` might be the best way to go (works in IE, Firefox, Chrome).

Answer (score 0):

Could you please try and check if this helps...

```
var selectedValue = this.get('value');
```

Comment: This creates a javascript error in IE... Pawel's response did guide me into the correct direction.